# make 'LastName' in findByOrderByLastName() dynamic

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

```
 int page = 0;
 int limit = 10;

 userRepository.findByOrderByLastName(new PageRequest(page, limit));
```

`page` and `limit` field is already dynamic. Now, I wonder if it's possible to make orderBy field dynamic also to avoid defining orderBy field (findByOrderByLastName, findByOrderByFirstName, findByOrderByMiddleName, findByOrderByHeightName... etc..) manually in my UserRepository.

Thinking of something like:

```
userRepository.find("lastName", new PageRequest(page, limit));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UserRepository**

```
Page<UserRole> findAll(Pageable page);
```

**Controller**

```
this.userRoleRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(offset, limit, new Sort(new Order(Direction.ASC, sorter[0]))))
```